# Recursive relation and relative table query with sub-queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue with my table that has recursive relation and relative table. My goal is to get all Employees that are supervisors and who has employees assigned with no Reviews done or where most recent review was done more than 3 months ago.

Here is the schema:

Employee

```
| ID | Name| BirtDate| Salary | SupervisorID |
```

This is an `Employee` table that has a `Supervisor` which is also an `Employee`.

Review

```
| ID | PerfomanceRating| Comment| ReviewDate| EmployeeID|
```

I came up with this type of query , but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
    (FName + ' ' + LName) AS Name, Employee.ID AS superID 
FROM 
    Employee
WHERE 
    Employee.IsSupervisor = '1' 
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM Employee  
         LEFT JOIN Review ON Employee.ID = Review.EmployeeId 
         WHERE Employee.SupervisorID = Employee.ID 
         GROUP BY ReviewDate
         HAVING ReviewDate IS NULL 
             OR MAX(ReviewDate) < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE())) > 0
```

So in the end of the day I would need `EmployeeID` and `Name` of the supervisor who has employees with no reviews done or most recent review done more than 3 months ago.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the ids of the supervisors and make a join to `employee` to get their names.
Then join to `employee` again, this time to get the employees under each supervisor.
Then join to a query that returns the max `ReviewDate` for each employee.
Finally group by supervisor and set the condition in the `having` clause:

```
select (se.fname + ' ' + se.lname) Name, s.id superID
from (select distinct supervisorid id from employee) s
inner join employee se on se.id = s.id
inner join employee e on e.supervisorid = s.id
left join (
  select employeeid, max(reviewdate) reviewdate
  from review
  group by employeeid  
) r on r.employeeid = e.id 
group by s.id, se.fname, se.lname
having count(case when coalesce(r.reviewdate, dateadd(month, -4, getdate())) < dateadd(month, -3, getdate()) then 1 end) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
SELECT (FName + ' ' + LName) as Name, Employee.ID as superID 
FROM Employee
WHERE Employee.IsSupervisor = '1' 
AND (
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                    FROM Review
                    WHERE  Employee.ID = Review.EmployeeId)
    OR  EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM Review
                WHERE  Employee.ID = Review.EmployeeId
                GROUP BY Review.EmployeeId
                HAVING MAX(ReviewDate) < DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
                )
)
```

Comment: There is no column `IsSupervisor` in the table Employee.

Comment: I just copied the code above and revised. You're right, there is no IsSupervisor column in given table.

Answer (score 0):

*#Mike Bashkatov :IF **IsSupervisor** column avalable in Employee table then As per my understanding below mention query give you desired output.*

```
SELECT (FName + ' ' + LName) as Name, Employee.ID as superID FROM Employee OEMP
WHERE Employee.IsSupervisor = '1' AND 
EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM Employee  INNER JOIN Review ON Employee.ID = Review.EmployeeId 
WHERE  Employee.SupervisorID = OEMP.ID 
GROUP BY ReviewDate
HAVING  MAX(ISNULL(ReviewDate,'01-01-1900')) < DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select (FName + ' ' + LName) as Name, Employee.ID as superID
from employee supervisor
where
(select count(ID) 
from employee 
left join Review on review.EmployeeID = Employee.ID and ReviewDate > DATEADD(month, -3, GETDATE()) --only join reviews that were in the past 3 months
where employee.supervisorID = supervisor.ID 
and Review.ID is null ) > 0) > 0
```

Basically, it is getting all of the employees who have a sub-employee and on the sub-employees, it is joining only those with reviews in the past three months. Then it is filtering out all of the sub-employees with any joined reviews.